# Where is the Dispose method implemented in the Component class library

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, interface, garbage-collection

Well I am trying to understand the release of memory procedures which can be done explicitly by code.

I see in the below MS thread that Dispose method is implemented in Component class. Here I have three doubts.

1. Component class derives from IDisposable, however, in this class library, I find it is not implementing the method Dispose and not even it looks "public void Dispose() { }". But when I just write a class and declare a method without any body, it gives me compile time error saying, I should define the body or make it abstract. Why is this difference?
2. I generally used this way, say for example, "connection.Dispose();" in the finally block to dispose sqlconnection. I understand that, SqlConnection is derived from DBConnection which in turn in derived from Component. When I looked at the Component class, I see just the declaration of the method "public void Dispose();" Then where it is actually implemented?
3. I also see some code that specifically implements like the one given in the MS website below. They declare a bool variable for Dispose status and have a new Dispose method where they call the Component Dispose on the object. They also use Kernel32 method CloseHandle for unmanaged resource. What is the use of this method? I never used this for my SqlConnection (Which is also an unmanaged resource) while disposing it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx

Could somebody please help me understand the three questions above in a brief way too. I am just learning all these. Thank you

Comment: Fwiw, Dispose() has **NOTHING** to do with memory.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Disposes the unmanaged and managed resources and reclaims memory is what I learnt. The MS website says "Objects that implement the IDisposable interface can call this method from the IDisposable.Dispose method to prevent the garbage collector from calling Object.Finalize on an object that does not require it."

Comment: Where are you seeing that `Component` does not implement `Disponse`?  The documentation clearly shows that it does.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then you learned wrong. The Garbage collector is responsible for cleaning up memory from an object, even if you dispose it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: The point I am trying to understand is, GS.SupressFinalize. When I went through above MS site, I learned that, I can prevent the overhead/duplicate execution of finalize by GC when I use dispose through "GC.SupressFinalize". On reading that, I have got all my queries above.

Comment: @shf301: Sorry, I didn't mean that. I mean to say, "Implementation of a method" means, writing its body? I DO NOT see that when I see in Visual Studio by pressing F12 and reaching to component class. That is my concern. I am not able to understand if "public void Dispose();" is  called implementation. According to me, anything that ends with a semi colon is declaration. Thats my concern. Another big concern which I am not able to understand is, all of the class library code by pressing F12, I see similar codes, where all methods ends with semicolon and when I do this in a class, error pops up.

Comment: You are just getting confused by the way the IDE shows you info about classes in the .NET framework, like Component.  It does not show you the source code, you don't have the source code for all the .NET framework classes.  Microsoft has it.  It just shows you the "outline" of the class, just the declarations.  Same thing you see in Object Browser.  You don't write C# code that way yourself.  Your questions are otherwise well covered in any intermediary book about the .NET framework.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you Hans Passant, that resolved atleast 95% of my concern on this thread. Just learning more to understand these things better (Especially the IntPtr handle they use here from Kernel32). Your reply helped me a lot, thanks again, I wasn't aware of that and that concern was always lingering on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to be clear about is that Dispose() has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with memory. The IDisposable pattern is entirely about cleaning up *unmanaged* resources... that is, cleaning up anything and everything *except* memory.

`Component.Dispose()` is documented here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx

Notice the following except:

> After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the Component so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the Component was occupying.

Again, we see that Dispose()-ing an object is a separate issue from releasing memory.

In the case of `SqlConnection`, there is an inheritance heirarchy at work. There is an empty `Dispose()` method on the `Component` type itself (empty methods are legal). The method is empty, because the base class doesn't itself have any unmanaged resources to worry about. The `SqlConnection` type *overrides* the base implementation, so that it will close the connection to the server.

Now let's talk about finalizers. Finalizers also have nothing to do with memory, except that they are called by the garbage collector. The purpose of a finalizer is to release unmanaged (non-memory) resources when an object is collected. If you're building a class that uses an *abundant* unmanaged resource, such that there is no risk for contention or exhausting the resource, a finalizer is enough by itself, and Dispose() serves no purpose. However, nearly all computing resources have some degree of scarcity, such that you may not want to wait on the garbage collector before releasing them. The garbage collector might not collect an object for some time, and so the Dispose() pattern exists to provide a way to release unmanaged resources in a timely, predictable way.

The goods news is that, most of the time, you don't need to worry about finalizers. You only need to implement a finalizer if you are building an entirely new kind of unmanaged resource. As an example, if you have a type in your program that manages your connection to a Sql Server database by wrapping the SqlConnection class, you don't need a finalizer. This may be a new class, but the the SqlConnection type *will* ultimately handle releasing your database connection. You should, however, implement or make use of IDisposable in your type, so that the connections it manages will be released promptly. On the other hand, if you are building an entirely new kind of database engine to compete with Sql Server, or were to re-implement the Sql Server connection protocols from scratch, you would want a finalizer.

Sometimes, your Dispose() method will need to *suppress* finalization. You might do this if, for example, trying to free your unmanaged resource a second time, after you've already disposed it, would cause an unnecessary exception.

I think I've covered most of the points from your three questions, but there are a few things still to address:

> it looks "public void Dispose() { }". But when I just write a class and declare a method without any body, it gives me compile time error saying, I should define the body

That method has a body. `{ }` *is* the body of the method. It's just that it's empty.

> where is [SqlConnection.Dispose()] actually implemented?

You're looking at the IDE. That only shows method declaration and a basic description. There's more code there. If you really want it, the [full .Net source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) is available.

> They also use Kernel32 method CloseHandle for unmanaged resource. What is the use of this method?

That's just a method specific to disposing that particular kind of resource. Part of the purpose of the IDisposable pattern is providing a standard place to put this kind of thing, so that you as programmer don't need to know about that stuff to correctly dispose an object.

Comment: Joel, I am reading your valuable inputs. However, when I started first two lines, I am afraid to say, I see "// If disposing equals true, dispose all managed" in the MS website which I gave above. It says it cleans the managed resource as well. I also read that, its only Finalize which disposes ONLY managed resources. But Dispose cleans both managed as well as unmanaged resources. Please help me understand. I wanted to learn.

Comment: @Divine remember, that code is called by the finalizer, which only runs during garbage collection. The garbage collector will clean up the ram at this time, but just as part of doing it's own thing. I don't know where you read that Dispose cleans managed resources, but it's wrong. It's really very simple: 1. The garbage collector cleans up managed resource. Period. Nothing else does. 2. `Dispose() _should_ clean up unmanaged resources, if you've done everything right. 3. If something goes wrong, the finalizer is the emergency/last ditch chance to clean up unamanged resources.

Comment: Joel, thank you, read and understood your full writings, helped me a lot. Today only I learnt about finalize and dispose. Thank you again. However, could you please give me some examples of managed resources? (Because MS document says, Dispose can OPTIONALLY through overloaded method, can cleanup managed resources). Also, why Finalize method is not visible inside the Component class in IDE?

Comment: Joel, to add, I also will do "Dispose" as well as "GC.Collect" inside the dispose so that, it reclaims memory of unreferenced objects forcefully. Is that correct?

Comment: @Divine There is exactly one managed resource: Memory. I question where you see documentation on MSDN claiming dispose can clean up a managed resource. It can't. Addtionally, calling GC.Collect() inside dispose will have _no effect_ on the object you are disposing. **Don't do it.**

Comment: Joel, thank you. Please see the method dispose with parameter boolean in the MS link below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx.... That line says, it can optionally releases managed resources.I am confused now. Even the link on my original post has a boolean valued strategy to release managed resource. I am afraid.

Comment: @Divine It's confusing, but what that refers to is calling `.Dispose()` on other managed resources that themselves implement IDisposable, but it doesn't actually release any memory.

Comment: Joel, thank you. Well let me take some more time and understand it still better about finalizer internals. I will seek your help, if I have any queries. So the bottomline is, all memory cannot be collected using Dispose or Finalize but GC.Collect(); right? And somwehere I heard, GC.Collect is not a good practise to use, is that so? Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly:

```
public void Dispose() { }
```

**has** a body - it is just an empty one. There is no difference here. Actually, though `Component.Dispose` is:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

The idea is that you `override` the `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` method if you want to add logic.

Secondly, if you are calling `connection.Dispose()` like that, then you are **doing it wrong**. You should be using a `using` block:

```
using(var conn = ...)
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // etc etc
    }
    // look ma, no finally
}
```

Your third point, and the MSDN article you cite, is simply an example of when you might *actually need to do this*. The `CloseHandle` method is simply an illustration of an **unmanaged resource**. This is key, because you *don't use finalizers to clean up managed resources - only unmaged*. As such, an example that involves an unmanaged handle is simple an excuse to illustrate:

- calling `Dispose(false)` from a finalizer
- `override` the `Dispose(bool)` method
- having some code (the handle) get cleaned up from both the finalizer and disposal (separately, `Dispose(false)` and `Dispose(true)`)
- having some code that only gets executed for the `Dispose(true)` case - i.e. onward disposal

Comment: Marc, thank you. Yes, I then was using "using" block. But ideally, if I implement thie Dispose method in finally when I use try/catch, how it differs from using "using"? Is there any difference? I think its just reducing number of lines of code, and elegant look?

Comment: @Divine it is removing opportunities to get it wrong; it is about making a pit of success. Doing cleanup in `finally` (when it can be done via `using` instead) is just asking for errors.

Comment: Marc, thank you, I will remember that. However, I am not able to figure out where the Dispose method is mentioned as Virtual which you said "protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)". I am sorry if that was silly question. I do not see this method Dispose marked as Virtual in component class. I am just learning all these concepts newly.

Comment: @Divine there are two `Dispose` methods; one `public`, non-virtual and parameterless (which implements the `IDisposable.Dispose` contract); and one `protected virtual` with a parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Marc, thank you so much, yes, I see that, I was silly, sorry. Well I am understanding all of it now with time :) Thank you for helping me understand, appreciate it greatly. I am also reading the pointers you gave me.